# Getting error while web scraping using python requests module

Tags: python, python-3.6

Trying to grab the content of website using python 3.6.2.Getting below error.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.amazon.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied
 (_ssl.c:748)'),))
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("https://www.amazon.in/")
r.content
```

Help me in fixing this!

Comment: looks like your system rules `access denied` in router or by firewall

Comment: Yup, works for me, which version of python and requests are you using?

Comment: @JulienPalard  python version is 3.6.2, requests module version is 2.18.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try *http* instead of *https*. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can check your connection and ability to communicate with TLS protocol by typing following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.amazon.in:443
```

Anyway, your python code is correct and works for me.

Comment: >>> openssl s_client -connect www.amazon.in:443
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    openssl s_client -connect www.amazon.in:443
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax